# Is there a tool or plugin that enables menu search on windows, like on the mac?

Tags: windows-7

I prefer the mac because it allows me to search the menu of any program. That way I can work very fast and don't have to remember where all the commands are hidden. And even if I know where they are in the menu hierarchy, it's way faster to type it into the help search bar in and hit enter.

Does anyone know of a plugin or tool that adds this kind of search for windows?

I mean the **application menu**! The one that always sticks at the top of the screen on the mac. NOT the spotlight search or start menu on windows! Here's an example: On Safari the menu has this items: **Safari, File, Edit, View, History, Bookmarks, Window, Help, ...** and so on. On the mac, you can search **through these items** and hit ENTER to execute.

NOT the start menu. NOT spotlight. The application menu. The features of the application. Seriously. Not even kidding! Windows isn't aware of this important feature that speeds up your workflow in heavy applications like Photoshop by a whole magnitude.

Comment: What you're asking about searching is usually called the “menu bar”.

Comment: BugAlert is asking about this feature — https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IP__mFL7d4 
And it drives me nuts too, that Windows does not have this. It should be SO EASY. 
Sure, this is 5 years later, but it STILL doesnt exist.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you might be looking for is called [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net):

[image]

[Launchy is a free cross-platform utility designed to help you forget about your start menu, the icons on your desktop, and even your file manager.

Launchy indexes the programs in your start menu and can launch your documents, project files, folders, and bookmarks with just a few keystrokes!][3](http://www.launchy.net/)

Comment: -1 BugAlert and I are looking for the same thing: A way to search the menus WITHIN any given Windows application (not the Windows start menu)

Comment: I think it should be possible to add this to Launchy as a plugin (as long as the application implements Active Accessibility, which will make it possible to reveal the menu contents to other programs without having to open all the menus). Note that a 100% solution is not possible since there are programs that build (or complete) their menus (or submenus) dynamically when they are opened only (and that don't care about accessibility). Maybe ask in Launchy forums?